# Error in Perl oneline command

Tags: regex, perl

```
perl -pi -e 's|\x20|; s|\x90|' log.bin
```

gives me this error

```
Backslash found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s|\x20|; s|\"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s|\x20|; s|\"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What am I doing wrong? the line intended to replace all bytes with 0x20 to 0x90...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 half statements, instead of one complete one. You're probably looking for

```
perl -pi -e 's|\x20|\x90|g' log.bin
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two incomplete substitutions in that command, you say substitute `\x20` without specifying what it should be replaced with, then separately say replace `\x90` again omitting the replacement. This is a syntax error.

the correct syntax is

```
s|\x20|\x90|g ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You formatted the s command wrong. Try this:

```
s|\x20|\x90|g;
```

The g means global and the formatting is necessary for the command